# Explain generic linked list in C

Tags: c, data-structures

Kindly explain push function. I could not get why loop is used . For char and int (new_node->data=new_data) works fine . But for string , it doesn't . For string , error is produced. If char(%c) is printed for new_data in push() method then only first character is printed , while if char(%c) is printed for new_node->data then last characater is printed.

```
// C program for generic linked list
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

/* A linked list node */
struct node
{
    // Any data type can be stored in this node
    void  *data;

    struct node *next;
};

/* Function to add a node at the beginning of Linked List.
   This function expects a pointer to the data to be added
   and size of the data type */
void push(struct node** head_ref, void *new_data, size_t data_size)
{
    // Allocate memory for node
    struct node* new_node = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    new_node->data  = malloc(data_size);
    new_node->next = (*head_ref);

    // Copy contents of new_data to newly allocated memory.
    // Assumption: char takes 1 byte.
    int i;
    //Why loop is used for copying data from new_data to new_node data.
    for (i=0; i<data_size; i++)
        *(char *)(new_node->data + i) = *(char *)(new_data + i);

    // Change head pointer as new node is added at the beginning
    (*head_ref)    = new_node;
}

/* Function to print nodes in a given linked list. fpitr is used
   to access the function to be used for printing current node data.
   Note that different data types need different specifier in printf() */
void printList(struct node *node, void (*fptr)(void *))
{
    while (node != NULL)
    {
        (*fptr)(node->data);
        node = node->next;
    }
}

// Function to print an integer
void printInt(void *n)
{
   printf(" %d", *(int *)n);
}

// Function to print a float
void printFloat(void *f)
{
   printf(" %f", *(float *)f);
}

/* Driver program to test above function */
int main()
{
    struct node *start = NULL;

    // Create and print an int linked list
    unsigned int_size = sizeof(int);
    int arr[] = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50}, i;
    for (i=4; i>=0; i--)
       push(&start, &arr[i], int_size);
    printf("Created integer linked list is \n");
    printList(start, printInt);

    // Create and print a float linked list
    unsigned float_size = sizeof(float);
    start = NULL;
    float arr2[] = {10.1, 20.2, 30.3, 40.4, 50.5};
    for (i=4; i>=0; i--)
       push(&start, &arr2[i], float_size);
    printf("\n\nCreated float linked list is \n");
    printList(start, printFloat);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The loop just copies the data. It acts like `memcpy(new_node->data, new_data, data_size);` This is used, because your linked list is designed to hold any data type. In C, that means raw bytes and `sizeof`s.

Comment: `/ Any data type can be stored in this node
    void  *data;`.   Hmmm `long double` likely does not fit.  A pointer to a function may not fit either.  Good enough for object pointers though.

Comment: Also Pointer arithmetic operation to `void*` is invalid. (It's GCC extension)

Comment: I think you want something like `*( ((char *)new_node->data) + i)`.  The [`memcpy()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43854183/explain-generic-linked-list-in-c#comment74744005_43854183) would be better.

Comment: [sample of string (char*)](http://ideone.com/oMryPz)

Comment: Is it necessary to allocate space for storing data? Why can't it be directly allocated to node?

Answer (score 0):

yes , we can also do `new_node->data=new_data` instead of using this loop

```
for (i=0; i<data_size; i++)
            *(char *)(new_node->data + i) = *(char *)(new_data + i);
```

but there is difference between them. when we simply using `new_node->data=new_data` we are shallow copying.therefore two pointers pointing to the same location i.e if you change the values of arr[] then automatically the values in the struct changes. 
when you using loop you are deep copying i.e if you change the values of the arr[] then the values of the struct will not get changed.
run the below code to understand the differnce.

```
// C program for showing shallow copy in generic linked list
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

/* A linked list node */
struct Node
{
    // Any data type can be stored in this node
    void  *data;

    struct Node *next;
};

/* Function to add a node at the beginning of Linked List.
   This function expects a pointer to the data to be added
   and size of the data type */
void push(struct Node** head_ref, void *new_data, size_t data_size)
{
    // Allocate memory for node
    struct Node* new_node = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

    new_node->data  = malloc(data_size);
    new_node->next = (*head_ref);

    // Copy contents of new_data to newly allocated memory.
    // Assumption: char takes 1 byte.
    int i;
    // no loop just normal assignment of new_data
        new_node->data=new_data;
    printf("\n");

    // Change head pointer as new node is added at the beginning
    (*head_ref)    = new_node;
}

/* Function to print nodes in a given linked list. fpitr is used
   to access the function to be used for printing current node data.
   Note that different data types need different specifier in printf() */
void printList(struct Node *node, void (*fptr)(void *))
{
    while (node != NULL)
    {
        (*fptr)(node->data);
        node = node->next;
    }
}

// Function to print an integer
void printInt(void *n)
{
    printf(" %d", *(int *)n);
}

// Function to print a float
void printFloat(void *f)
{
    printf(" %f", *(float *)f);
}

/* Driver program to test above function */
int main()
{
    struct Node *start = NULL;

    // Create and print an int linked list
    unsigned int_size = sizeof(int);
    int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5}, i;
    for (i=4; i>=0; i--)
        push(&start, &arr[i], int_size);
    printf("Created integer linked list is \n");
    printList(start, printInt);
    printf("\n");
    // changing the values in arr[]
    arr[1]=45;
    arr[3]=1000;
    //printing the struct
    printf("printing the struct after changing the values in the array \n");
    printList(start, printInt);
    /*
    // Create and print a float linked list
    unsigned float_size = sizeof(float);
    start = NULL;
    float arr2[] = {10.1, 20.2, 30.3, 40.4, 50.5};
    for (i=4; i>=0; i--)
        push(&start, &arr2[i], float_size);
    printf("\n\nCreated float linked list is \n");
    printList(start, printFloat);*/

    return 0;

    }
```